# How to add CSS info to Python pandas to_html()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add CSS to the top of HTML generated by `DataFrame.to_html()` by `df.style.set_properties(color="green")`

The `df.to_html("filename.html")` generates the following output

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
```

......

The question is how can I print the CSS info at the top of the output file?

```
<a color="green"/a> <=====
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897366/pandas-to-html-using-the-style-options-or-custom-css)

Comment: [**Shameless self promotion**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511805/2336654)