# How to format pandas columns or cells based on conditions

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to format ( set background color or bars or highlight) columns in pandas dataframe using styler ? I want to format each column different on certain conditions .
In dataframe df for column C all values less than 99 are red, for column B containing dates getting the bars.

Comment: Are you using a web based IDE like jupyter notebooks?

Comment: No, I am passing the output to Outlook Application, No web IDE. @AngelRoman

Comment: Yes you can do that. You can find information on how to style dataframes here[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html] and a similar question about rendering it to outlook here[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897366/pandas-to-html-using-the-style-options-or-custom-css].

Comment: They both are similar but dont work to my needs.