# How to not escape characters when using pandas styles

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

If I want to add html inside a normal dataframe, I can do

```
df.to_html(escape=False)
```

To ensure special characters are not escaped.

On the other hand if I want to use styles, I do

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues').render()
```

How can I have both?

The render method seem to accept `escape=False`, but it doesn't do anything.

Additionally, my requirements are such that I would like to:

1. have the gradient be applied on the original `df`
2. be able to change some individual cells afterwards (specifically, I would like to make some cells clickable by surrounding them with `<a onclick="...">...</a>`

Anyone knows how to do this?

EDIT

Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'i': i*i } for i in range(10)])
df['clickable'] = df['i'].apply(lambda i: f"""<a onClick="alert('you pressed ' + {i})")>Click for {i}</a>""")
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='PuBu')
```

In the example above, I managed to get the 'clickable' column to be clickable. But I would like the 'i' column to be clickable too, while retaining its style.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897366/pandas-to-html-using-the-style-options-or-custom-css

Comment: Could you post a sample input and expected output? You can easily create such an example like this: print(pd.read_clipboard().to_dict()) then put that dict into ->
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({...})

Comment: @Andreas - I added an example

Comment: @dkreeft - that post just explains what the render method is. My question is about how to use render but have the 'escape=False' set as well.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but it seems what you are looking for is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'i': i*i } for i in range(10)])
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='PuBu').format("""<a onClick="alert('{0}')">Click for {0}</a>""", subset=['i'])
```

This way `apply` allows you to apply gradients based on values and `format` allows you to tell styler how you want to render values (everywhere or in specific columns using `subset`).

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking for. Turns out the argument for format can also be a lambda, which is what I need in my case. But you deserve the bounty :)